# Merge conflicts while merging my current branch to a master in github of Android Studio

Tags: android, github

I have a **current branch**(registration_signin_apis),i tried  to merge current branch in to a **master** by creating pull request but i got  merge conflicts like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYwlb.jpg
when i tried to edit this file to resolve my conflicts i didn't get any edit option 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7bBA.jpg

In my previous *pull request* i had seen edit option so i resolved my conflicts by editing there,but now in this pull requests it   *Showing  66 changed files  with 2,644 additions and 601 deletions.*

I think it has too many conflicts thats why its not showing **edit option** and also it suggested that please use command line to resolve your conflicts as we mentioned here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNmr0.jpg

or use **git Hub desktop**

I tried that `commands` too in my `gitbush` and also i tried to merge  in **android studio** still no use

Can  any one suggest me how to resolve merge conflicts and lead to pull request Success...?

Comment: 66 changed files sounds suspicious; you probably have not even touched that many files in total.  Maybe abort the merge and try it again from the Git bash.

Comment: try to merge via AndroidStudio, it has nice and clear interface for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this in console from root of your project:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge registration_signin_apis
```

There will be conflicts and you can resolve it in Android Studio:
VCS -> Git -> Resolve Conflicts

Comment: ya i tried it in git bash bit i got conflicts (VCS->Git->Resolve Conflicts(disabled) tried to activate that ,but i can't

Comment: @uma try to `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Version Control window to see which files have merge conflicts. Then open them in the usual editor pane to view and edit them as you wish to resolve the conflicts.